# Output Buffer + Pdf - PHP

Tags: php, pdf, stdout

I have a page that uses the glob function and file_get_contents to have a few html files and store them in the buffer.

So I want to convert this buffer ob_get_contents() to an pdf file.

What is the best way to do that? how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating PDF files from HTML and CSS, check out [DOMpdf](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/).

While this solution doesn't support the full range of HTML and CSS and its rendering can be a pain sometimes, it has one advantage: it does not require any special binaries to be installed (like wkhtmltopdf). It should run on your average shared PHP hosting.

Usage example:

```
<?php
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

$html =
  '<html><body>'.
  '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
  'templating system.</p>'.
  '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");

?>
```

Comment: Im getting an error  Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent

Answer (score 1):

why using the outputbuffer for this? you have it in variables using `file_get_contents` and can simply create your pdf with the data from the variables. when using `ob_get_contents` all it does is return the outputbuffer and what you normally do with the result is saving into a variable...

btw. you do want to convert html into pdf? If yes have a look at [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

Answer (score 1):

If `ob_get_contents` contains html files they are so many solutions out there that can achieve what you want. I think you should look at the following

- [PrinceXML](http://princexml.com/)
- [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)
- [TCPDF](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf)
- [HTML to PDF converter (PHP5)](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/)
- [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

Example using [Simple HTML 2 PDF using PHP](http://html2fpdf.sourceforge.net/)

```
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$pdf = new HTML2FPDF();
$pdf->SetTopMargin(1);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$pdf->Output('test.pdf','D');
```

Comment: I can't do that with HTML2PDF because Im getting several errors .

Comment: @user1642423 they are other options ... one would definitely work for you